# Match specific character, print if found

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to print each line from a file if they contain a single character in a specific position, to start with that is a '+' but i will run the same program using a '-'. The code runs but doesn't provide an output, i am sure it is a very simple error as i have checked the regex and that works!

FILE1 Data:

```
3628 -a
9712 +T
11004 -a
11379 -a
12715 +T
14184 +T
```

Output:

```
9712 +T
12715 +T
14184 +T
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $outputfile = "/Users/edwardtickle/Documents/indelfinal.txt"; 

open FILE1, "/Users/edwardtickle/Documents/indelcount.txt";

open (OUTPUTFILE, ">$outputfile");

while (<FILE1>) {
    if (/^(\d+)\s+(\S)(\S)/) {
    if ($2 =~ m/'+'/) {
    print OUTPUTFILE "$1 $2$3\n";
    }
}
}

close FILE1;
close OUTPUTFILE;
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ($2 =~ m/'+'/) {
```

This is a regular expression match, so it's not doing what you think it does. This will match if `$2` (the `+` or the `-` or whatever) contains a sequence of at least two apostrophes (the length of `$2` is always 1, so this can never happen).

You want a string comparison instead:

```
if ( $2 eq '+' ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The following regex can help you determin `+` at second last(specific) position in a string

```
m/\+.$/
```

For example

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;


open FILE1, "input";


while (<FILE1>) {
    if ($_  =~ m/\+.$/ ) {
    print  "$_";
    }
}

close FILE1;
```

will produce output as

```
9712 +T
12715 +T
14184 +T
```

**What it does?**

- `\+` matches a `+`
- `.` matches any single character
- `$` matches the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there can only ever be one `+` or one `-` in your input, so there's no point in splitting the line into fields before you do the test. This is all you need.

```
while (<FILE1>) {
    print OUTPUTFILE $_ if /\+/;
}
```

or, in a single-line command

```
perl -ne'print if /\+/' indelcount.txt > indelfinal.txt
```

Note that the latter requires your current working directory to be `/Users/edwardtickle/Documents`

Answer (score 0):

It gives what you expect

```
use warnings; use strict;
open('new',"file1");
my @ar = <new>;
my @vz = grep{m/\+/g} @ar;
print @vz,"\n";
```

I used the `grep` operator for match the particular word with sentence within file.